# Why is this item always executed in the Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I wrote the following Makefile. But when I execute the `make` command, the sentence `gcc -shared -o ../lib/libCfunc.so objFile/cacheOp.o objFile/fileOp.o objFile/linuxOp.o objFile/commonFunc.o` is always executed. Even if I did not modify any files, and executed multiple `make` commands consecutively.

Doesn't `objFile` depend on `$(libObjs)`? Why is only this sentence being executed all the time?

```
cc=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -O0 -fPIC -lm

libObjs=objFile/cacheOp.o objFile/fileOp.o objFile/linuxOp.o objFile/commonFunc.o 
all:  objFile test
test: testFunc.c  
        $(cc) $^ -lCfunc -o $@ $(CFLAGS) 
objFile: $(libObjs)
        gcc -shared -o ../lib/libCfunc.so $(libObjs)
objFile/cacheOp.o: Bodyer/cacheOp.c Header/cacheOp.h Header/cacheDetails.h
        $(cc) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
objFile/fileOp.o: Bodyer/fileOp.c Header/fileOp.h 
        $(cc) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
objFile/linuxOp.o : Bodyer/linuxOp.c  Header/linuxOp.h
        $(cc) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
objFile/commonFunc.o : Bodyer/commonFunc.c  Header/commonFunc.h
        $(cc) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY : clean
clean :
        -rm $(libObjs)
```

Comment: Why do you use the name objFile when it is a directory?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objFile file doesn't exist, so Make tries to build it.

Since your rule doesn't actually create a file called objFile, the next time you run Make, the objFile file *still* doesn't exist, so Make tries to build it again. And so on.